# Skip and top functions for paging in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Can we do Skip and Top for paging 
like

> SELECT TOP 10 PostId FROM Contacts

in DocumentDB ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what language you are working with or if you still need an answer but This is what I did to work around the TOP X until the feature is implemented.

I wanted to run a query and only grab the top 1 from the results w/o returning the entire collection. In the SDK I found the feedOptions object that was able to only select the TOP X that i needed.

The code:

.NET ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.aspx)):

```
       var options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };
       var query = _documentclient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyObject>(this.MyObjects.SelfLink, "SELECT * FROM MyObject m WHERE m.Enabled = false", options).AsDocumentQuery();
       var topItem = (await query.ExecuteNextAsync<MismatchedAnswer>()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Node.js ([GITHUB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/57c01a36cd202e54d34d2bc2acc32af38b949c3a/core_sdk/lib/documentclient.js#L679))

```
client.queryDocuments(collectionSelfLink, "SELECT * FROM MyObject m WHERE m.Enabled = false",{maxItemCount: 1}).nextItem(function(err, element){
    console.log([err, firstItem]);
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Skip and Top are not implemented *yet*.

Please voice your opinion by voting for this feature on the Azure Feedback forum:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take